# Lazy registration and accessing your order via email without a registration

Tags: security, user-experience

I'm curious about the technologies used to securitize user flows where there is no registration involved (I've seen this called "[lazy registration](https://ui-patterns.com/patterns/LazyRegistration)").

I've seen several e-commerce websites where users can buy stuff without having to register. They provide an email and their payment details, and they are emailed with their order.

Sometimes, these sites send an e-mail with a link that allows users to view their order. My question is: what are the patterns and security best practices around this type of unauthorized access to an order? Is there a name for this? How do companies ensure that no personally identifiable information (PII) is leaked?

Comment: Some PII does leak, I think for example UPS tracking IDs list the destination address but they might have fixed that.   I don't think you can do more than (a) use long GUIDs for the order links to mitigate blind guessing. (b) severely rate limit requests to further mitigate blind guessing, and (c) include the minimal information necessary to the task, like just the order status.  Customer support probably needs full access to the guest order to resolve problems.